# Как работает следующая строка globals()[f](a, b)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть программа, которая эмитирует работу с пространствами имен. На вход программе подаются следующие данные:

Input:
9
add global a
create foo global
add foo b
get foo a
get foo c
create bar foo
add bar a
get bar a
get bar b

```
namespace = {'global':{'parent':'None','childrens':[]}}

def create(a,b):
    namespace[b]['childrens'].append(a)
    namespace[a] = {'parent':b,'childrens':[]}  

def add(a,b):
    namespace[a]['childrens'].append(b)
    namespace[b] = {'parent':a}

def get(a,b):
    if b in namespace[a]['childrens']:
        print(a)
    else:
        if namespace[a]['parent'] != 'None': 
            get(namespace[a]['parent'],b)
        else:
            print('None')

for i in range(int(input())):
    f,a,b = input().split()
    globals()[f](a,b)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает последняя строка программы globals()f?
Скажем, первый ввод данных 9, потом add global a...т.е. будет globals()'add' и как результат будет вызываться функция add ...но почему так происходит и почему  квадратные скобки и потом круглые???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `globals()` возвращает словарь с объектами глобальной области видимости.

Среди них будут и Ваши функции:

```py
{'create': <function create at ...>, 'add': <function add at ...>, 'get': <function get at ...>}
```

Поэтому инструкция `globals()[f]` вернёт функцию с именем `f`.

Затем, благодаря круглым скобкам в конце: `globals()[f](a,b)`, функция будет вызвана с аргументами `a` и `b`.

---

Если ввести `1 add global a`, то произойдёт следующий вызов:

```py
add('global', 'a')
```

Comment: nomnoms12 спасибо Вам огромное!